# python+postgresql: Convert string literal to regex

Tags: python, regex, postgresql, string

I want to execute a query where I match a column name using a regex to my variable, `s`. `s` is a string literal and may contain things like `?`, `*`, `.`, etc. I want to convert `s` so that `?` turns into `.{0,3}`, so that all of its remaining regex symbols remain literals, and then add `.*` to the end. examples:

```
Hi -> Hi.*
Fo?ar -> Fo.{0,3}ar.*
F.a*rx -> F\.a\*rx.*
F.a?*rx -> F\.a.{0,3}\*rx
```

What's the best way to do this? Mostly I'm unsure how to quote a string literal so the regex symbols aren't interpreted as regex symbols (e.g. `.` -> `\.`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print '.{0,3}'.join(re.escape(part) for part in s.split('?')) + '.*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `re.escape(string)` method.

Which states:

> Return string with all
>   non-alphanumerics backslashed; this is
>   useful if you want to match an
>   arbitrary literal string that may have
>   regular expression metacharacters in
>   it.

Check out the [re module page.](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Comment: ah 'escape' is the word, i was thinking 'quote'